# Background color of TextView inside ListView not beeing applied in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have seen lots of questions/answers here about changing background colour of a TextView inside a ListView, but in my case none of them seems to work.

I have in my 'BaseAdapter' class in GetView method:

```
   String status = item.getStatus().trim();
int backgroundColor = 0;            
if (status.trim().equals("S")) {
    backgroundColor = R.color.corSeparada;
}
if (status.trim().equals("F")) {
    backgroundColor = R.color.corFinalizada;
}
if (status.trim().equals("E")) {
    backgroundColor = R.color.corEncerrada;
}
if (status.trim().equals("N")) {
    backgroundColor = R.color.corNova;
}
holder.campoCorStatus.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
```

This should be enough to paint some TexViews background with 'green, red, black or yellow' colours, but results in a strange background colour as shown in the picture:
[image]

The left column should be the one which should change the background color, I also tried to change the background color of another TextView (the right side), no success at all.

Comment: Make sure you are setting and getting your holders.  Can you show your whole getView()

Comment: Irrelevant, but no need to `trim()` twice.

Comment: String status = item.getStatus().trim(); System.out.println(status);  lets see the getView() method...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So while I can't see the rest of your code and determine if you're using the adapter wrong (which I think is also the case), what I *can* do is tell you that you're not setting your colours correctly.

Use this: 
`holder.campoCorStatus.setBackgroundResource(backgroundColor);`

OR

`holder.campoCorStatus.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(backgroundColor));`

setBackgroundColor actually takes in a numerical value for colour (like 0xFFFF0000), but you're passing an id FOR a colour in, not the actual value for that resource id.